# Error in Azure WebJobs- continuous

Tags: azure-webjobs, exit-code, azure-webjobs-continuous

What does the below error shown in Azure web job log file mean?

" **: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code - 1073741818** "

What is the cause for this error?

Comment: Did you run your WebJobs in local working fine? If possible, I hope you could show me more details about your codes or exception picture.

Comment: Please start with [this guidance](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues) to help isolate to a non-WebJobs scenario.

Comment: We managed to solve the issue. It was a bug that prevented us from accessing the data from storage. But anyways Thanks, guys.